# I don't have an android phone but i need a screenshot for my app on google play

Tags: java, android

I don't have an android phone so is it possible that i take a screenshot on the emulator or something?

Comment: This is not directly related to programming, so unrelated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a screenshot of your app via Android Studio.

[Capture Screenshots and Videos in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html)

If you are using eclipse, then click link below.

[Take Emulator Screen Shots in Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-taking-emulator-screen-shots-eclipse/)